# Push Notification Ionic 3 - Angular 4 redirect

Tags: angular, push-notification, ionic3

I'm developing an app with Angular 4 and Ionic 3. The app sends a notification between users of the app when either of them are close to each other.
This is similar to what happens with the Facebook feature that shows you which of your friends are close to your location.
Currently, I can send and receive the notifications but I need the notification to take me to a specific rout of the app when the user click on it and not to just open the app.
How could I do that? Has anyone tried this before?